# How to get the position of touch in a simple windows phone 8 app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am making an app for windows phone 8.
On one of the pages of the app, I want to get the co-ordinates of the touch.

I tried searching on net but I got results related to games.

I want to know is it possible to get the position of touch on canvas/or any other component in a simple app. 
If yes, plz guide me through it.

Answer (score 0):

Hook up to Tap event of the Control, and use GetPosition of event args.

```
<Canvas Tap="HandleTap/>


private void HandleTap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    Point point = e.GetPosition(null);
}
```